# Embed Browser (safari, firefox, chrome) + Access DOM in Java

Tags: java, webkit

Is there a way to:

1. embed a browser view in Java Frame of some sort (I'm on Mac OSX)
2. tell the browser to render a page
3. have Java have access to the DOM (i.e. delete nodes, create new nodes, create new nodes with CSS styles, change innerHTML of nodes) ...

Thanks!

I believe WebKit will be the easiest, but I'm not attached to it. The core rendering engine of say, Safari, Firefox, of Chrome will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/, or try [Qt WebKit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtwebkit-guide.html) through [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/).

Update: this looks very good too: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozswing/