# web interface using jQuery for Java application

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm developing a Java application that handles and analyses different types of data and what I want is to display this data in an user friendly way by using plots and tables in a HTML webpage using jQuery, Highcharts and few other JavaScript libraries.

What's the best way to do this? Is Google Web Toolkit my best bet?

My current solution is to do the analysis and the display of the data completely separated. I run all the analysis in Java an then export the results in Json files and build the plots with JavaScript scripts. Although, this way I'm having issues in handling the increasingly growing JavaScript files. Moreover, a more integrated interface where I could handle everything together would be the perfect solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Hove you looked at any of these solutions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948254/embed-browser-safari-firefox-chrome-access-dom-in-java

Comment: These solutions seem to integrate a browser window in a java app. What I want is to handle a webpage from java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your only problem the size of the resulting javascript file?  If so, there are a couple of options.

### 1) Use websockets.

[Websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) allow you to have a live connection between the server and the browser.  This would allow you to stream the data instead of sending it between the backend and the browser as a server.

### 2) Serialize your data in a more compressed manner.

JSON is great.  It's biggest strengths being it being human readable and playing exceptionally well with Javascript.  However, it will add some extra bytes to your data.  Not many mind you, but some.  However, if size is truly being a problem, then consider creating a more [serialized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) way to pass data, where you have an understanding of how the data should look, then on the browser, you can deserialize it into json, and continue as normal.

### 3) Compress and decompress

This one is a bit more convoluted, but will probably save you more bytes for the price of slower performance.  You can zip the data up before passing it to the client, and unzipping on the browser.  See this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294297/javascript-implementation-of-gzip) for more details on compression and decompression with javascript.

### 4) Leave it as is.

I guess I don't have enough context, but I think what you are currently doing should be fine enough.  There is always ways to improve, but not sure exactly what you want to improve.

Cheers.

Comment: I think your answer say it all, probably any other alternative will drag me into improving certain aspects, like file sizes, but bringing other problems. Thanks!